# Change combobox value according to another combobox value?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm kind of new about C# and WPF projects. So here is my issue.

I have 2 Combobox filled with string lists.

> According to the value of my first combobox, I would like to change
>   the list available in the second combobox.

Here is my code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //creation de listes
    List<string> themesE17 = new List<string>();
    List<string> themesH17 = new List<string>();
    List<string> themesE16 = new List<string>();
    List<string> themesH16 = new List<string>();



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        initLists();

        string value = comboSaison.Text;
        Console.WriteLine("The value of season combobox " + value);

    }

    public void initLists()
    {
        //saison 2017
        themesE17.Add("Ete 17 Theme1");
        themesE17.Add("Ete 17 Theme2");

        themesH17.Add("Hiver 17 Theme1");
        themesH17.Add("Hiver 17 Theme2");

        //saison 2016
        themesE16.Add("Ete 16 Theme1");
        themesE16.Add("Ete 16 Theme2");

        themesH16.Add("Hiver 16 Theme1");
        themesH16.Add("Hiver 16 Theme2");
    }

    private void comboSaison_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboSaison.Text == "Ete 2017")
        {
            comboTheme.ItemsSource = themesE17;
            Console.WriteLine("1st if E17");
        }

        else if (comboSaison.Text == "Hiver 2017")
        {
            comboTheme.ItemsSource = themesH17;
            Console.WriteLine("2nd if H17");
        }

        else if (comboSaison.Text == "Ete 2016")
        {
            comboTheme.ItemsSource = themesE16;
            Console.WriteLine("3rd if E16");
        }

        else if (comboSaison.Text == "Hiver 2016")
        {
            comboTheme.ItemsSource = themesH16;
            Console.WriteLine("4th if H16");
        } else

            Console.WriteLine("Error in selection !");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, my `Console.WriteLine` shows me thats the program goes in all if cases in a random way when i select my values in the first combobox.

Help would be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: What is the comboSaison selected item when you change your selection?
Try using comboSaison.SelectedItem and find out.

Comment: it is "Ete 2017" as selected value, so it should be the themesE17 list in the combobox named comboTheme @PeterB

Comment: Using databinding I think a more reliable option would be to bind to an observeablecollection of strings in xaml, and then update the content of that collection rather than the binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ComboBox has items. So just find selected and its caption.

```
private void comboSaison_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = (ComboBox)sender;
        var ind = obj.SelectedIndex;
        var selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)obj.Items[ind];
        switch ((string)selectedItem.Content)
        {
            case "Ete 2017":
                comboTheme.Items.Clear();
                foreach (var item in themesE17)
                    comboTheme.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = item });
                break;
            case "Hiver 2017":
                comboTheme.Items.Clear();
                foreach (var item in themesH17)
                    comboTheme.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = item });
                break;
            case "Ete 2016":
                comboTheme.Items.Clear();
                foreach (var item in themesE16)
                    comboTheme.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = item });
                break;
            case "Hiver 2016":
                comboTheme.Items.Clear();
                foreach (var item in themesH16)
                    comboTheme.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = item });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

Also better change switch(text) to switch(index), to prevent Case missmatches and misstypes in words.
p.s. sorry for my english
Note: this for WPF, not for WinForm solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it, but it seems that there's a reference missing because the code won't execute...

Comment: Is the comboSaison_SelectionChanged marked as the event for SelectionChanged?

Comment: @PeterB yes it is.

Comment: And it's not executing at all? Or is it breaking at the if(ind<0) return; part?

Comment: @PeterB not executing for the moment

Comment: Did you add  "ToArray()" at the end of themesE17 and themesH17?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134353/discussion-between-jay-and-sergio).

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks for your help again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just change all your `List<string>` by `ObservableCollection<string>`

Comment: Thanks for answering but, this doesn't solve the "AddRange" error

Comment: Oh I thought it was working, you have an error at runtime? On which line?

Comment: On my own code yes no runtime error, just displaying random lists on my 1st combobox selected values, but i have runtime errors with sergio's solution @Safe

Comment: If your code was working when you shared it just go back to this version and try it with just change the `List` to `ObservableCollection` Your code was ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134355/discussion-between-jay-and-safe).